# Check for boolean values and convert them to numbers in an object

Tags: javascript

I have got a an object that has values **true** and **false** for certain keys.I need to find which keys has got a boolean value and convert them to 1 and 0 respectively,how do I do it?Any help or advice much appreciated.

```
var obj ={
    "serviceid": 123,
    "accountid": 456,
    "name": "Test in progress",
    "number": [
      {'setNumber':true},
      {'setNumber':false},
    ],
    "settings": {
      "playback": false,
      "attachfile": true,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a boolean using `Number` or the `+ operator`.

```
Number(true);  //=> 1
Number(false); //=> 0
+(true);       //=> 1
+(false);      //=> 0
```

[**edit** based on comment]
you can use `typeof` to check if a value evaluates to a boolean:

```
var somebool = true
   ,sombool_isBoolean = /^boolean$/i.test(typeof somebool) //=>true
   ,nobool = 'true'
   ,nobool_isBoolean = /^boolean$/i.test(typeof nobool)    //=>false
;
```

So for you object you could do something like:

```
var objnr0 = obj.number[0].setNumber;
obj.number[0].setNumber = /^boolean$/i.test(objnr0) ? +(objnr0) : objnr0;
```

[**edit2** based on comments]

A bit of a 'dirty trick' to replace true/false boolean values in the object without looping the object:

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse(
              JSON.stringify(obj)
                .replace(/:true/gi,':1')
                .replace(/:false/gi,':0')
            );
```

Comment: `parseInt(true)` would try to `parseInt("true")` (`NaN`)

Comment: thanks guys,but how do I check which keys has got a boolean value from the object

Comment: @manraj82 I was afraid this was just a how to access object question in disguise

Comment: @KooiInc thanks for your answer but so do i loop through the object and sub objects and check if the values are boolean ?

Comment: @manraj82 see edits. Looping through the object is a different question, not related to converting a boolean ;~)

Comment: @KooiInc its not just the setNumber that has got a boolean value.The obect I have placed in the question is part of a very long object.I need something that can check for the values dynamically,is this possible?

Comment: @KooiInc  My apologies for not being clear,what I need is to check for keys in an object that has got boolean values and then convert them to numbers